# Cannot scroll to id with PrimeVue Dialog, vue3-simple-typeahead and Vue 3 router push

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

There is a view that loads files with `<router-view/>`. That contains the [Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/dialog) and the [vue3-simple-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-simple-typeahead) for searching .

```
<Dialog header="Search" v-model:visible="displayBasic" > 
        <vue3-simple-typeahead
          id="typeahead_id"
          ref="typeahead_ref"
          placeholder="Search"
          :items=baritems
          :minInputLength="1" 
          :itemProjection="itemProjectionFunction" 
          @onBlur="typeheadblur"
          @selectItem="selectItemEventHandler"  
        > 
        </vue3-simple-typeahead> 
    <template #footer> 
        <Button label="Close"  @click="closeBasic" />
    </template>
</Dialog>
```

the objects of the vue3-simple-typeahead is like so

```
const baritems = ref([ 
        {  href:"hello.html#F1", title:"hello" },
        ....
])
```

I have a function to close the Dialog

```
const closeBasic = () => {
  displayBasic.value = false; 
}
```

and also I have the `selectItemEventHandler` function, called when a user picks anything from the vue3-simple-typeahead. In that function I want to first close the Dialog itself and then take the `href` of the selected object and do a `router push` to load a file in `<router-view/>`

```
const selectItemEventHandler = (item)=>{  
  displayBasic.value = false;
  let part = item.href.split('.')[0]
  let term = item.href.split('#')[1]
  router.push({ name: part, force: true ,params: { term } }) 
}
```

In the file that is loaded according to the `router.push`, I watch the url params to scroll to the right id, based on the router params

```
  watchEffect(()=>{
    id = route.params.term; 
    let el = document.getElementById(id);  
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}); 
  })
```

ISSUE

this does not scroll to the right id of the file loaded for some reason that I cannot understand. I get no errors in the console. I type in vue3-simple-typeahead I click something , the Dialog closes , the url changes, the file loads, but cannot scroll to the right id. From `selectItemEventHandler` if I remove the `displayBasic.value = false;`, it scrolls, but it will not close the Dialog.

How can I fix this?

Comment: After router pushing, do you get the hash on the URL? Btw, a minimal example to reproduce your problem on https://stackblitz.com/ would make us easier to help

Comment: No, I overwrite that functionality with vue router. But the router works and does its job. Anyway, check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ds9ig5?file=src%2Fviews%2FProject.vue) out, I tried my best to make it work ,but I get an error, but the code and logic is there

Comment: It's hard to help if you can't reproduce it. Try to call the scroll function in `selectItemEventHandler` after a small timeout instead of `watchEffect` to see if it works